# Insert caption to text in Word

Tags: windows, microsoft-word

I'm using word 2010 and I have some snippets of code that need captions. Similar to a table or an image but text.

So far, I used the caption style and created needed captions but it doesn't work in the same manner like real image captions. And, also, it doesn't group the text. What good is it have a caption if you don't know which part of the text it belongs to?

How could it be done?

Comment: So far, I used the caption style and created needed captions but it doesn't work in the same manner like real image captions. And, also, it doesn't group the text. What good is it have a caption if you don't know which part of the text it belongs to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a text box (added from the Insert tab) to add grouped text.

[image]

Right click the border to add a caption.

[image]

---

If using a text box with a caption doesn't have what you are looking for, then I suggest making a table with two rows. You can add a table from the `Insert` tab and resize to your liking.

[image]

Insert your code in the upper row and caption in the lower.

[image]